# How to determine change points in data?

Tags: regression, change-point

I have a data which consists of multiple measurements for proportion of cells for controls and patients. As you can see from the figures, the proportions increase with age and this increase starts at the earlier ages for patients.

So, is there a way that I can determine such a change point and quantify its significance?

I have checked some time-series packages but as far as I can see they require one measurement per time point.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**Controls**
[image: Controls]

**Patients**
[image: Patients]

Edit: You can reach the data with the following [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19wXwluqT11_LVRIkIRUsFoSDVW3geWtoRUQoLm-17d4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: As a rough and dirty answer … I would average the multiple readings at each point and use time series methods using the averages rather than the multiple readings at those points that had multiple readings ...Not perfect but things seldom are

Comment: would it make sense to select different time points and compare the means of left and right sides with a t-test and selecting the change point as the one with the lowest p-value?

Comment: no because the observations WITHIN each group are probably autocorrelated thus violating the test of means.

Comment: @IrishStat that is a question about the design that should be posed to the OP.

Comment: @Adamo … quite true

Comment: The linear model is seldom appropriate for fractal relationships. Suggest you transform variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the proportions increase with age and this increase starts at the earlier ages for patients.

1. I wager these data are highly amenable to log transformation. I am distrustful of the scatterplot due to the long positive skew of the response. Nevertheless, the hypothesis is well framed as the above
2. The natural test for the hypothesis as above is to fit the linear *and quadratic terms* of age with an interaction by "case"-status, whatever the disease is. You can test the hypothesis about the inflection point using linear combinations of the coefficients
3. If this is a retrospective analysis, be cautious of lead time bias. That is, "cases" were more likely to be identified as "cases" because surveillance of "proportion" (whatever that is) was performed sooner and more frequently

Edit: illustrating code below

```
with(df, plot(age, lproportion, type='n'))
by(df, df$group, function(df) {
  Col <- unique(df$group)
  points(df$age, df$lproportion, col=Col)
  # if any interest in the smoothing spline result
  # lines(with(na.omit(df), smooth.spline(age, lproportion)), col=Col)
  qfit <- lm(lproportion ~ age + I(age^2), data=df)
  uage <- sort(unique(df$age))
  lines(uage, predict(qfit, newdata = data.frame('age'=uage)), lty=2, col=Col)
})
legend('topleft', pch=1, col=unique(df$group), legend = unique(df$group))

library(lmtest)
fit0 <- lm(lproportion ~ group + (age + I(age^2)), data=df)
fit1 <- lm(lproportion ~ group*(age + I(age^2)), data=df)
lrtest(fit1, fit0)
```

The log transform of the response was taken and is plotted in the figure below, with the black points representing the proportions of "CD8+ RO+ CCR7- d0" in controls and the red points the "CD8+ RO+ CCR7- d0" in patients. Quadratic trendlines were estimated using least squares regression. We remark that the estimated concavity differs. That is, cases and controls have the same estimated proportion at age 20 and at age 60, however, at age 40 the cases have a predicted proportion of 20 whereas controls have a predicted proportion of about 12 (confirm this).
[image]
To test the hypothesis that quadratic curves differ between the two samples we fit age and the square of age along with an effect for group in a linear model, and then further adjusted for the interaction between group and age and its square. The 2-degree of freedom Likelihood Ratio Test was not statistically significant ($p = 0.1981$).

Comment: All points on the figures signifies different individuals; controls are taken from healthy people and all patients have the same specific disease. I could not understand the second bullet point. can you elaborate more on the subject?

Comment: @eonurk care to share the data?

Comment: sure. here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19wXwluqT11_LVRIkIRUsFoSDVW3geWtoRUQoLm-17d4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @eonurk revised with code and "loose" write up

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: I learned some much from your answer but I have new questions too. So, the first one is that, why do we compare the models with and without the interactions? Second, if the test was statistically significant, how would it help me find the inflection point?